# Get child element at position relative to parent element (not window) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

consider the following html:

```
<div id="p"><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
```

I need a javascript function `getElementByPos(element, x, y)` that returns reference to child element (span) based on a position (x and y) relative to container (`<div id="p">`)

For example, `getElementByPos(p, 0, 0).innerText` should return `"1"`
and `getElementByPos(p, 10, 0).innerText` should return `"2"`

Function `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` is not suitable for my needs, because it does not work when container is not visible (for example, when page is scrolled).

Comment: Have you looked into using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)?

Comment: Can you add some more information about where x and y are coming from? Usually `document.elementFromPoint` would be associated with a mouse click, is that what is happening here?